# Is there an R function to order a matrix using two or more columns?

Tags: r

I simulated a data of 3 columns

```
aa <- rep(seq(0,1,0.05), seq(21,1,-1))
  bb <- NA
  for(i in length(seq(0,1,0.05)):1){
    bb <- c(bb,rep(seq(0,1,0.05),len = i))
  }
  bb <- bb[-1]  
  cc <- 1-(aa+bb)
Dominance <- cbind(aa,bb,cc)
```

Then, in my problem, a row containing (0,0,1) is equal to a row containing (1,0,0) and (0,1,0).
So I use this code below to organize my data

```
for(i in 1:dim(Dominance)[1]){
    Dominance[i,] <- Dominance[i, order(Dominance[i,], decreasing = FALSE)]
}
```

The problem is that when I try to order using this code bellow, they order the first column well, but not the second column.

```
Dominance[order(Dominance[,1],Dominance[,2],Dominance[,3]),]
```

I got this as a result

```
  [1,] 0.00 0.00 1.00
  [2,] 0.00 0.00 1.00
  [3,] 0.00 0.00 1.00
  [4,] 0.00 0.05 0.95
         ...
  [59,] 0.00 0.50 0.50
  [60,] 0.00 0.50 0.50
  [61,] 0.05 0.35 0.60
  [62,] 0.05 0.35 0.60
  [63,] 0.05 0.05 0.90
  [64,] 0.05 0.05 0.90
```

The problem starts on line 61, once I have in the first column 0.05 and in the second column 0.35, but in the line 63 I have the same value in the first column (0.05) but in the second one I have a small value than 0.35.

Any ideas?

I have tried to use two other functions but they got the same results.

Comment: Sorry, I just fix the code.
aa is the first column, it is in the code now.
Thank you!

Comment: Are `data` and `Dominance` the same thing? I don't really get what you're trying to do with the for loop. Try skipping it—just create the data, then call the `order` line. Is that not ordered the way you want?

Comment: Yes, data and Dominance is the same thing. Sorry for this error, I was trying to fix my code and get this error.
So, I used that loop because if I have a row containing (0.5, 0.5, 0.90) and a row containing (0.9, 0.5, 0.5) they represent the same thing to me. So I first order every row, to then order the columns.

Comment: Please explain what you want and show the correct answer.

Comment: I am expecting this output 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00 0.05 0.95 0.00 0.05 0.95 .... 0.00 0.10 0.90 ... 0.00 0.50 0.50 0.05 0.05 0.90 .... Look in the first column, when we see the transition from 0.00 to 0.05, the row should be (0.05 0.05 0.90) but the results is showing (0.05 0.35 0.60)

Answer (score 1):

With the tidyverse approach, this is as simple as:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  arrange(aa,bb) %>%
  as.matrix()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's fine if what the OP wants is a data frame, but they haven't indicated that. Their output is still a matrix

Comment: %>% as.matrix() haha

Comment: Thank you a lot, but the code did not work.
I easily can do what I want using excel, but I am really curious about what is going on in that data that is not ordering correctly.

Comment: Let's see your correct answer. I find this code working for what I understood in your question.

Comment: I am expecting this output 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00 0.05 0.95 0.00 0.05 0.95 .... 0.00 0.10 0.90 ... 0.00 0.50 0.50 0.05 0.05 0.90 .... Look in the first column, when we see the transition from 0.00 to 0.05, the row should be (0.05 0.05 0.90) but the results is showing (0.05 0.35 0.60)